# FluidSynth fails in script but works in ipython

Tags: sound, python

I am starting to test the use of fluidSyinth to create midi files. My first script is very simple. It perfectly works in ipython but not as an script in the command line, where it does not anything, no errors and no sound. I am using python2.7 in both (ipython and comand line). I am using ubuntu. This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
from mingus.midi import fluidsynth as c
import time

for i in range (0,100,1):
    c.play_Note(i,0,100)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I decided to test fluidsynth directly from the comand line in an ubuntu-terminal using

```
fluidsynth /usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2 mymusicfile.mid
```

and I got this:

```
FluidSynth version 1.1.6
Copyright (C) 2000-2012 Peter Hanappe and others.
Distributed under the LGPL license.
SoundFont(R) is a registered trademark of E-mu Systems, Inc.

Cannot connect to server socket err = Connection refused
Cannot connect to server request channel
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2013 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
configuring for 44100Hz, period = 1024 frames (23.2 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Type 'help' for help topics.

>
```

but the midi file is not reproduced, shouldn't it?

This command works fine in the ubuntu-terminal:

```
fluidsynth -a alsa -m alsa_seq -l -i /usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2 mymusicfile.midi
```

but the problem remains in python. The script I copied at the beginning of this thread works fine in ipython if I run it as:

```
run script.py
```

however it does not run when I execute it from the ubuntu-terminal on the command line as:

```
python2.7 script.py
```

I tried the following script that also works in ipython:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import time
import fluidsynth

fs = fluidsynth.Synth()
fs.start()

sfid = fs.sfload("example.sf2")
fs.program_select(0, sfid, 0, 0)

fs.noteon(0, 60, 30)
fs.noteon(0, 67, 30)
fs.noteon(0, 76, 30)

time.sleep(1.0)

fs.noteoff(0, 60)
fs.noteoff(0, 67)
fs.noteoff(0, 76)

time.sleep(1.0)

fs.delete()
```

and I get the following output when I run it from the ubuntu-terminal:

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2013 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
configuring for 44100Hz, period = 1024 frames (23.2 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
JackTemporaryException : now quits...
```

although it does not make any sound.

Comment: How are you running the code as a script as opposed to “in IPython”?

Comment: Yes, in iPython I am running it as a script: " run script.py "

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release and python version and how did you install `mingus`?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: I did install mingus using " sudo easy_install mingus "

Comment: python version 2.7

Comment: Bad syntax in your fluidsynth command : missing -i before the soundfont name. look https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FluidSynth

Comment: @laugeo you were right. I have corrected the command and it works. However, the problem remains in python... I have edited the main text of this entry adding more information